# kubernetes newer api-server shows errors 'Resetting endpoints for master service "kubernetes" to'

Tags: kubernetes

i have a kubernetes installation that works fine, currently with one api-server.
(version 1.0)

but when i try to start a second api-server (version 1.2alpha), on a different computer with the same config, it seems to work (i can access it with curl), but i get these error-messages every 10seconds:

```
controller.go:290] Resetting endpoints for master service "kubernetes" to...'
```

(the line is longer, i removed the remaining parts because i am not sure how much of it contains private info)

the api-server is started like this:

```
kube-apiserver --logtostderr=true --v=0 --etcd_servers=something --address=something --allow_privileged=false --service-cluster-ip-range=something
```

(i replaced the correct values with 'something')

starting the second one with version-1.0 does not show these messages, so it might be an issue of version-mismatch, but i am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

`kube-apiserver` needs to know how many apiservers are in the cluster. You must provide the `--apiserver-count=X` flag to every member of the cluster, where X is the number of apiservers in the cluster. If X is too small, apiservers will fight over the endpoints for the kubernetes service (as you observe). If X is too large, then wrong values will linger in the endpoints for the service and some percentage of client requests to the Kubernetes API from within the cluster will not connect to a running apiserver.

In the future, we will probably make apiservers negotiate this value amongst themselves, but for now you need to set the flag correctly.

Comment: i see (i've edited my original message thinking it's a version-mismatch problem, but maybe it was this one). so, how am i supposed to increase the count from 1 to 2? should i first restart the single api-server with --apiserver-count=2, and then start the second? or first start the second with --apiserver-count=2, and then restart the first with --apiserver-count=2? also, is the documentation wrong? i was reading http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/high-availability/#replicated-api-servers and the yaml-file for the api-server does not mention the --apiserver-count

Comment: i checked the github repo, and it seems this flag is a new thing in kube1.2, that probably answers why it was not an error with the older version. can i even run multiple api-servers with kube1.0?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention, this flag was unfortunately not exposed until recently (although the setting always existed internally).

I think the order you should use to maximize availablity is to start the new apiserver with --apiserver-count=2, then restart the existing apiserver with the new flag.

Comment: One more thought: I definitely would not recommend running multiple apiservers split-version for longer than it takes to do a rolling upgrade. That configuration is not tested as of 1.2.

Comment: What would happen if a master in the cluster goes down so there is an apiserver less? Kubernetes should be resilient to that, but if, with this apiserver-count parameter, during that master is down you have a higher number than the currently running apiservers, that will create problems with clients not connecting to the running apiservers within the cluster, as you previously said. Is there any solution for that?